# Oracle: Search string in all tables

Tags: oracle

is there a way to search a pattern string in all columns, all tables, in a Oracle database?
Should be case-insensitive.
For example, I'd like to find in which tables/columns there is the string 'alpha'.
Strings with values: 'alphabeth', '001alpha', 'alpha001' should be returned also.

Has anyone idea how to write a query like this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Luis

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query ? Sure NO.
A PL/SQL procedure using the meta data found in user/all_tab_columns, EXECUTE IMMEDIATE to execute dynamic queries using INSTR or LIKE with COLLATE BINARY_AI or BINARY_CI.
("all columns": no, only the one of string types: CLOB, CHAR, VARCHAR2, NVARCHAR2, ... BLOB may be more annoying because some are storing JSON there... but no way no know without knowledge of the application, or maybe by checking the presence of a IS JSON constraint on the column... )

But seriously what could be the business need for such requirement? Forensic?

Comment: You can do it with a query via a (dynamic, but not PL/SQL) XML query - Lalit shows some options in the linked question.